# Use a variable in twig literal

Tags: twig

Twig has date function such as

```
{% if today > date("+2days") %}
```

I want to use a variable in '+2days'
for example

```
{{ x }} = 2

{% date('+xdays') %}
```

I can make it in PHP such as

```
date("+{$x} day");
```

But I use {} in twig,
it shows error.

How can I slove this?

Comment: `date()` is used for formatting, You need to use [date_modify()](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/date_modify.html) to modify a date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use set with concatenator in Twig like this

```
{% set x = 2 %}

{% set var = '+' ~ x ~ 'days' %}

{% date(var) %}
```